# How to groupby dataframe rows and filter against all occurrences from a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

### Situation

There is an `df` that is holding elements, each element could have different types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,2,2,2],
    'type':['a','b','a','b','c']
})
```

This `df` should be filtert against a list and show only the `ids` that `types` *contains* all the `list`:

```
['a','b','c']
```

Expected `id` in this case is: 2 cause all of its `types` a,b,c are in the list.

### The approaches that I tried

Grouping by `id` and get a list of its `types`, but no idea how to compare against the `list` or to apply something like *set(list).issubset(types)*:

```
df = df.groupby('id')['type'].apply(list)
df.reset_index(name = 'types')
```

Query against `list`, but with result that are all `types` in:

```
df.query('type in ["a","b","c"]')
```

Would be great to get a hint - Thanks

Comment: *,,, that `types` are all in the `list`* doesn't sound like what you are seeking for. Do you mean `types` **contains** all the list?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks  - Your right, it meant types contains all the list, edited it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `set.issubset` with `groupby.apply`

```
l = ['a','b','c']
s = df.groupby("id")['type'].apply(lambda x: set(l).issubset(x))
s[s].index
```

---

```
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

---

```
s[s].index[0]
#2
```

Comment: Looks like I wasn't that far away from a "solution" but glued more my fingers then the data :)  Thanks a lot, now direction is much more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You can check `isin` then `groupby`:

```
your_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df['type'].isin(your_list).groupby(df['id']).all()
```

Output:

```
id
1    True
2    True
Name: type, dtype: bool
```

Now, if you want to filter your original data, it's `groupby.transform`:

```
df[df['type'].isin(your_list).transform('all')]
```

---

**Update** if you are looking for `id` that **contains** all types in `list`:

```
valids = df['type'].isin(your_list)
mask = df[valids].groupby('id')['type'].nunique() == len(set(your_list))
mask[mask].index
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

Comment: Thanks - Interesting approach, without applying lambda to the group. will surely get familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `np.logical_and.reduce` in a list comprehension to check that all values exist at least somewhere in the group (accomplished via `groupby` + `transform('any')`). This might scale better if your list of values is small while your number of unique IDs is large.

```
import numpy as np
my_list =  ['a', 'b', 'c']

mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df['type'].eq(val).groupby(df['id']).transform('any') 
                              for val in my_list])
#array([False, False,  True,  True,  True])

df[mask]
#   id type
#2   2    a
#3   2    b
#4   2    c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare sets:

```
s = set(['a','b','c'])
df.groupby('id')['type'].apply(set).eq(s)
```

Output:

```
id
1    False
2     True
Name: type, dtype: bool
```

Comment: What if a group has `a, b, c, z`?

Comment: You are right. It works only with this special case.